# How to get details about the selected items using QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I'm using QTreeView with QDirModel like this:

```
QDirModel * model = new QDirModel;
ui->treeView->setModel(model);
ui->treeView->setSelectionMode(QTreeView::ExtendedSelection);
ui->treeView->setSelectionBehavior(QTreeView::SelectRows);
```

This works fine, however, I'm not sure how to get the details about the files I select. I've got this so far:

```
QModelIndexList list = ui->treeView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
```

But not sure what to do now, I'd like to get each file's name and full path. An example would be really great. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [fileInfo](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qdirmodel.html#fileInfo) method of the QDirModel to get file details for the given model index object, smth like this:

```
QModelIndexList list = ui->treeView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
QDirModel* model = (QDirModel*)ui->treeView->model();
int row = -1;
foreach (QModelIndex index, list)
{
    if (index.row()!=row && index.column()==0)
    {
        QFileInfo fileInfo = model->fileInfo(index);
        qDebug() << fileInfo.fileName() << '\n';
        row = index.row();
    }
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Just beat me to it...  A small detail: since the selection is set to be rows at a time, you can get the selection list as a list of each row's first column's model index, instead of all of the selected indexes.  See the selectedRows() function at http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedRows